Swagger XML Example Value Doesn't Obey XML Annotations on Class
Given this class:
    [XmlRoot("MySample", Namespace = "http://mynamespace.org")]
    public class Sample
    {
        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
        public string TimeStamp{ get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Property1")]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

I correctly receive the following XML from my action:
<MySample version="1.2" timestamp="4/12/2024 5:56 PM" xmlns="http://mynamespace.org">
  <Property1>My Value</Property1>
</MySample>

However, the swagger UI insists on showing the XML example as this:
<Sample>
    <Version>string</Version>
    <TimeStamp>string</TimeStamp>
    <MyProperty>string</MyProperty>
</Sample>

Is there a trick to get the Swagger UI to follow the XML serialization rules?

Try this. Add the XmlAttribute in a MySample class and then add the XmlElement

[XmlRoot(Namespace="http://mynamespace.org")]

public class MySample
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("timestamp")]
    public string TimeStamp{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Property1")]
        public Property1 Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Property1
{
    [XmlText]
        public string prop1Value { get; set; }
}

should output this:
<MySample version="1.0" timestamp="2013-01-01T00:00:00" xmlns="http://mynamespace.org">
    <Property1>Value</Property1>
</MySample>

and the OAS schema
components:
  schemas:
    MySample:
      type: object
      xml:
        name: MySample
        namespace: http://mynamespace.org
      properties:
      version:
        type: string
        xml:
          name: version
          attribute: true
      timestamp:
        type: string
        xml:
          name: timestamp
          attribute: true      
      Property1:
        type: string
        xml:
          name: Property1


The problem isn't with my class definition. The swagger.json does not output any xml properties to control serialization of the Example Value. I would have expected it to extract it from the xml data annotations.

just providing an alternative because maybe the generator you're using is looking for a particular construct
